# anchor link issues

Tags: html, navigation, positioning, anchor, nav

Ok so I have anchor links on my page and I have set my nav links to those anchors. The anchors work fine except they keep dropping me too low. I set the anchor links above the headers for each section but the anchor links keep dropping me below the headers. Here is my code for my nav and one of my anchors.

```
<div class="content-outer" id="top_nav">
            <div class="content-inner">
                <ul>


<li><a href="#home">Home</a><li>
<li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>





<div id="Layer-56" class="servicesheader png"  ><a name="services" id="services"></a
</div>

<div id="Layer-56" class="servicesheader png"  >
<img src="Layer-56.png" width="273" height="42" alt="servicesheader" class="pngimg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS for the problem? And maybe a screenshot or the actual url?

Answer (score 0):

Validate your markup. You are now using the same `id` value twice, which is forbidden. Instead of `a` elements with empty content, assign an `id` attribute to a natural element. Consider using heading markup (e.g., `h2`) for headings.

This probably won’t fix the problem at hand, but fixing the markup and posting a full example that demonstrates the problem (entire document or URL) will increase the odds of getting help.

The problem might be caused by CSS positioning, possibly by errors in CSS code.